# How to Write Spring Data JPA query for getting two counts after group by

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to write something like this

```
      SELECT oi.order_id,
             COUNT(oi.found)              as found,
             (COUNT(1) - COUNT(oi.found)) as not_found

      FROM orders_items oi
      WHERE oi.order_id = 43

      GROUP BY oi.order_id
```

Is it possible to write a query like this in  Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
You need to have an interface annotated with @Repository and that extends the JpaRepository. There you can create queries, when the out of the box syntax does not cover your needs you can annotate a method with @Query and write your query likes this.

```
@Query("SELECT oi.order_id FROM order_items oi ...")
List<MyEntityClass> findMyEntities()
```

You can pass parameters to use also in the method. The syntax is not identical with the native one because jpa offers some abstraction. For small examples you can look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. but can you pls tell me how to do aggregations ? If you see my question I am doing two aggregations there

Comment: I see that the count works normally, here some examples: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions
If you find it too difficult to convert it and you dont care for the jpa abstraction, you can just make native queries with the parameter
`nativeQuery=true`
after your query